# Rust Book 12.3 - unresolved import error [E4032]

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and working on the exercise in [Chapter 12.3 in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html).

I am pretty confident that my code is the same as that in the book (hard to tell for sure because of the 'snips'). However I get an unresolved import error when I try `cargo build` or `cargo run` from the project directory, `minigrep/`

`src/main.rs`

```
use std::env;
use std::process;

use minigrep;
use minigrep::Config;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let config = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        println!("Problem parsing args: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    });

    println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
    println!("In file {}", config.filename);

    if let Err(e) = minigrep::run(config) {
         println!("Application error: {}", e);

         process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

`src/lib.rs`

```
use std::fs;
use std::error::Error;

pub struct Config {
    pub query: String,
    pub filename: String,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result <Config, &'static str> {
        if args.len() < 3 {
            return Err("not enough args");
        }

        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();

        Ok(Config { query, filename })
    }
}

pub fn run(config: Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)?;

    println!("With text:\n {}", contents);

    Ok(())

}
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I'm using VS Code for editing and building and executing from the command line using cargo. I could not get the error to go away in the editor, but I was able to build and run with no problem using cargo. So I exited out of VS Code and restarted it. Fixed the problem, because VS Code is no longer showing the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just ran across the same problem when reviewing The Rust Programming Language. The way I got it to compile was to remove the line `use minigrep;` from src/main.rs and add `extern crate minigrep` to the top of the file. The other file can stay as it is. Not sure if this a typo in the book (if it is then it is in multiple versions) or if there is a change to the behavior of the Rust compiler to accommodate the new syntax and we are just using a version that is too old. For comparison my version is 1.31.0.

Comment: I just figured out where the problem is. In order for the code to work as shown in the tutorial you must make sure your project is in "2018" mode. In the Cargo.toml file put `edition = "2018"`  in the package section. Version 1.31.0 does this automatically when you create new projects but I had created my project before updating to 1.31.0 from 1.30.0.

Comment: Yes, I see the same behavior. It also looks like new projects I create are using version "0.1.0" by default, which must have been the cause of my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. When I was searching for solutions to my problem all I saw was your post with no replies. Once my code started to compile I thought I'd share my experience. Glad I could help.

Comment: Also, just so you know. The version you see is the default version for all new projects. That will always be the same on new crates and has nothing to do with the version of Rust. To get the version of Rust run this on the command-line: `rustc --version`.

Comment: None of the solutions with this answer seem to apply any longer. The other answer from user11090888 to use mod lib; use lib::Config: seems to be correct, consistent with the other documentation and actually works.

Comment: This solution is no longer work with the version 1.51.0 of rustc compiler.
Please should be promote as best answer the one of user11090888

Answer (score 33):

There is a contradiction between the code samples for the exercise in chapter 12.3 and the earlier section in chapter 7: '7.2 -- Modules and use to control scope -- Separating modules into different files'.

Using 7.2's syntax complies:

```
mod lib; //.. instead of 'use minigrep'
use lib::Config; //.. instead of 'use minigrep::Config'
```

Comment: This work around is not needed. Please follow the answer below by Tyler Brock. It worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Neither of the above answers is correct. Using `cargo clean` is the correct solution. The incremental build process that produces that red underline in the IDE is a result of cached information about the program and library.

```
$ cargo clean
```

Comment: This is indeed correct. Came across the same problem and this solution worked. Also I agree the above solutions look like workaround not the solution.

Comment: This is the right answer. Please update the accepted answer or upvote this guys

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a VSCode issue. Simply restarting VSCode makes the error go away, as discussed on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/vscode-rust/issues/686

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I accidentally chose the wrong file name for the `lib.rs`. Make sure the file is named `lib.rs` without a typo. Other file names do not work here because of the `use` statement.

When you write `use minigrep::Config`, the compiler will look for a `lib.rs` file in the current project `minigrep` to resolve the imports.